Prove that there exists some $i ≠ j$ such that $p\ |\ i\sigma(i) - j\sigma(j)$, where $1 ≤ i, j ≤ p - 1$ and $i, j \in \mathbb N$
Question:
Let $p ≥ 3$ be a prime number, $R = \{1, 2, \dots, p - 1\}$, and $\sigma = \{\sigma(1), \sigma(2), \dots, \sigma(p - 1)\}$ is a permutation of $R$. Prove that there exists some $i ≠ j$ such that $p\ |\ i\sigma(i) - j\sigma(j)$, where $1 ≤ i, j ≤ p - 1$ and $i, j \in \mathbb N$.
My Solution:
In my solution, I attempted to change the question a tad bit because I'm pretty sure the introduction of $\sigma$ feels unnecessary. As in, the terms $i, j, \sigma(i), \sigma(j)$ represent four elements from $R$, right? So, $i\sigma(i)$ and $j\sigma(j)$ are two products between four non-zero residues modulo $p$ taken pairwise.
With that in mind, I tried to prove the question via the Pigeonhole Principle. Let $k = \sigma(i)$ for now, which is an element of $R$. WLOG, suppose that $i ≤ k$. The number of distinct unordered pairs of elements $(i, k)$ that we can choose from $R$ is $n = \binom{p - 1}{2} + p - 1$. Now, let's match the products $ik$ of each $(i, k)$ pair to its respective residues (pigeons to pigeonholes).
It is easy to see that all the $(1, k)$ pairs' products will be distinct to each other modulo $p$, so they will adequately occupy each of the $p - 1$ pigeonholes individually, leaving us with $n - (p - 1) = \binom{p - 1}{2}$ pairs. Since $\binom{p - 1}{2} > 0$, i.e., $n > p - 1$, the remaining pairs' products will coexist with the former $(1, k)$ pairs' products modulo $p$.
Thus, by the Pigeonhole Principle, we have shown that we can find pairs for which $i_1k_1 \equiv i_2k_2 \pmod p$, i.e., there exists $i ≠ j$ such that $i\sigma(i) \equiv j\sigma(j) \pmod p$.
$$\boxed{\therefore p\ |\ i\sigma(i) - j\sigma(j)\ }$$
I don't know if this is completely right or not, but I feel that something's incomplete with my approach — like I'm supposedly missing something. Any help would be much appreciated. I would definitely be interested in a different solution as well!

The step "we can find [distinct] pairs for which $i_1k_1 \equiv i_2k_2 \pmod p$, i.e., there exists $i ≠ j$ such that $i\sigma(i) \equiv j\sigma(j) \pmod p$" is wrong. There are much more pairs $(i,k)$ than pairs $(i,\sigma(i))$.

Hint: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an Approach0 search, there's the AoPS thread Divisibility by a prime, which basically uses what Anne's comment above suggests, and states the problem comes from Romanian IMO TST $1986$.

I think I get it @AnneBauval.
Since all the elements in $R$ and $\sigma$ are distinct modulo $p$, by Wilson's Theorem:
$$1\sigma(1)\cdot 2\sigma(2)\cdot\dots\cdot(p - 1)\sigma(p - 1) \equiv 1 \pmod p$$
If there did not exist $i\sigma(i) \equiv j\sigma(j) \pmod p$, then that would imply that:
$$1\sigma(1)\cdot 2\sigma(2)\cdot\dots(p - 1)\sigma(p - 1) \equiv -1 \pmod p$$
which is a contradiction to the first statement. That right?

This was in John's link.
